# does kafka apply compression on rebalancing to transferred partitions

Tags: apache-kafka

Our new kafka cluster was running out of space faster than anticipated, so I took some measures to mitigate:

1) I turned on snappy compression for the topics in question: this was done on the broker-side with a "kafka-topics --config compression.type=snappy" command, so as not to interrupt producers

2) I doubled the number of kafka nodes in the cluster

3) I rebalanced the cluster.

These steps worked and we have bought some time.  I know that [1] only applies to newly-produced data, but I was wondering if partitions which were rebalanced to the new nodes would be compressed when they arrived at their new broker, or whether they would retain their original form (there was no producer compression, so they were all uncompressed).  The old nodes had some other stuff on them which makes it difficult to infer from a simple disk usage analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Records will be compressed and written to the new broker during the partition reassignment.

Comment: Thank you, do you have any links to documentation that explains this?

Comment: I am afraid there is no official document mentioning this although it's easy to be expected as a desired behavior.

Comment: It certainly is desired; I understand that there may be no documentation specifically stating this is the behavior, but have you personally seen this behavior?

Comment: Is there a link into the source that shows this choice?